# jQuery Smart Wizard Step Verification

Tags: jquery, html, smart-wizard

I am using jQuery Smart Wizard to save a form on each step, I have some input fields. I want to validate each field before going to the next step. 
please help me how can I achieve it.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#smartwizard').smartWizard({ 
    selected: 0, 
    theme: 'default',
    transitionEffect:'fade',
    showStepURLhash: true,
    toolbarSettings: {toolbarPosition: 'bottom',
    toolbarExtraButtons: [btnFinish, btnCancel]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can cheque that form is valid or not while clicking on next step.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#smartwizard').smartWizard({ 
        onLeaveStep:leaveAStepCallback,
        onFinish:onFinishCallback
    });

    $("form").validate({
        rules: {
            'student[business_representative_attributes][first_name]': 'required'
        },
        messages: {
            'student[business_representative_attributes][first_name]': 'Please enter first name'
        }
    });
});

function leaveAStepCallback(obj, context){
    alert("Leaving step " + context.fromStep + " to go to step " + context.toStep);
    // return false to stay on step and true to continue navigation 
    if ($('form').valid()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Smart Wizard 4

```
$("#smartwizard").on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {
     return confirm("Do you want to leave the step "+stepNumber+"?");
});
```

Comment: Thanx for help pratik but its not working what is 'username' is it the name of field? i have a field named  'student[business_representative_attributes][first_name]'  how will i validate it?

Comment: Username is just an example. You can use fields there. I have used username because I don't have your form fields.

Comment: $("form").validate({
        rules: {
            'student[business_representative_attributes][first_name]': "required"
        }
    });   This is not working. even when i am trying to debugg its not going inside 'leaveAStepCallback' function.

Comment: I have changed it in my answer.

Comment: do we need to define 'leaveAStepCallback' function?

Comment: No need to define function. You can write code inside function directly. But it will look good.

Comment: You can remove onFinish option because function for it is not defined.

Comment: yes i have removed it. but still i am not able to stop next step.

Comment: $('#smartwizard').smartWizard({ 
            selected: 0, 
            theme: 'default',
            transitionEffect:'fade',
            showStepURLhash: true,
            toolbarSettings: {toolbarPosition: 'bottom',
                              toolbarExtraButtons: [btnFinish, btnCancel]
                            },
        onLeaveStep: leaveAStepCallback,
        // onFinish: onFinishCallback
    });

Comment: $("form").validate({
        rules: {
            'student[business_representative_attributes][first_name]': 'required'
        },
        messages: {
            'student[business_representative_attributes][first_name]': 'Please enter first name'
        }
    });

Comment: function leaveAStepCallback(obj, context){
      alert("Leaving step " + context.fromStep + " to go to step " + context.toStep);
      // return false to stay on step and true to continue navigation 
      if ($('form').valid()) {
          return true;
      } else {
          return false; 
      }
  }

Comment: i guess onLeaveStep: leaveAStepCallback is not getting fired. i am not able to debug it any solution?

Comment: onLeaveStep: function(obj, context){
    alert("Leaving step " + context.fromStep + " to go to step " + context.toStep);
    // return false to stay on step and true to continue navigation 
    if ($('form').valid()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
},

Comment: you can write like this as well.

Comment: hey its worked i was using smartwizard 4 but now i try samrtwizard 3 and its worked. but facing some ui issues :)

Comment: i cant use smartwizard 3 please help me. why onLeaveStep is not working with smart wizard 4?

Comment: Because in smart wizard 4 method is changed. See my updated answer.
For more check this link http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard/documentation